# Autoplay function in embedded video vue.js?

Tags: html, vue.js

Is it possible to autoplay the embedded video in the website? Tried different solutions to make it work on vue.js but it won't. Even adding autoplay=1 in the link, doesn't work. I'm using the iframe code from youtube, which I will provide below.

```
<iframe width="1060" height="615" src="[Link]?autoplay=1controls=0" title="Youtube Video" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoplay with youtube iframe (embedded) only works if you mute the sound!

so

```
<iframe width="1060" height="615" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L_gGKD8UNKA?autoplay=1&mute=1" title="Youtube Video" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

by adding `mute=1` after `autoplay=1` it starts the video automatically

here is a [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/jankees/pen/BawRRZz) link!

Comment: Aw that's sad. I guess its not possible to have sound when autoplaying. Anyways, thank you so much!

Comment: May I follow, how about looping? I tried using autoplay, mute, but loop doesn't work @Jan Kees.

Comment: @rg_ by adding &playlist=VIDEOID&loop=1 after mute=1 It will loop! i have updated the codepen.io link so you can check that out!